# Where to find list of downloads in Safari 13.1 for macOS Mojave?

Tags: macos, mac, safari, mojave, data-transfer

I am using Safari 13.1 on macOS Mojave.

The **Downloads** icon button in the upper-right corner of Safari's toolbar is now gone. The **Customize Toolbar** feature does not offer any such widget.

Is there some other way to see a **list of recent downloads** and where they went?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open Safari Preferences window (by going to Safari Menu bar → Preferences... or using the keyboard shortcut <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>,</kbd>), go to the General tab and check if **Remove download list items:** is set to **Upon successful download**.

[image]

If yes, then the **Download** button is shown in the Safari toolbar (towards the right end of the Address and Search bar) as long as one or more download tasks are in progress. As soon as the last active download task completes, the **Download** button is automatically removed from the toolbar.

The **Show Downloads** command is also greyed out under the View menu if the **Downloads** button is not visible in the toolbar.

To view the button, you can change the **Remove download list items:** setting to a different desirable value.

Answer (score 0):

The downloads button will not be there, when there are no more downloads in the list.  The reference to your download probably aged off, based on your selection for download list removal in settings (Referenced in the prior post from Nimesh Neema).  Where they went is also in the settings   ... under "File download location".  By default this will be "Downloads", but you may have selected "Ask for each download", in which case, it would be wherever you put it.  You can open finder to find your downloads.  I suspect it will be in the default which is "Downloads", which should be a separate category on the left of Finder.  You can sort by date by clicking on the "Date added" column, or similarly sort by name by clicking on the "Name" column.  That should help you find your download.